# How can I change cursor for disabled <button> or <a> in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I use *cursor: not-allowed* on ***button*** or ***a***? I tried the following:

```
.not-allowed {
     pointer-events: auto! important;
     cursor: not-allowed! important;
}
```

My button looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled not-allowed" href="https://www.example.com" role="button">Test</a>
```

Without the pointer-events is activated, the cursor can not be changed. But if ***pointer-events: auto***, the ***button*** or ***a*** is clickable. If the ***pointer-events: none*** the cursor doesn't change.

Please help me, I despair!

Comment: Maybe use `pointer-events: auto !important;` (space before the exclamation mark)

Answer (score 163):

This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16088) in Bootstrap

The proposed solutions :

```
button:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

or if you have this kind of structure :

```
<li class="disabled">
  <a href="#">My Link</a>
</li>
```

then

```
li.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
li.disabled a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper, *some* hair pulling is right - the realisation is removing pointer events on the nested a tag, which this prescribes perfectly. Thanks to this some of our hair is retained!

Answer (score 47):

Use this:

```
.not-allowed {
     cursor: not-allowed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can wrap your button in span like below

```
<span>
   <button> click me </button>
</span>
```

Now in css don't allow pointer events on button and make cursor disabled for wrapper.

```
 button {
     pointer-events: none;
     opacity: 0.7
   }


   span {
       cursor: not-allowed;
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

**use**   `onclick="return false;"`

```css
.not-allowed{
 cursor: not-allowed! important;
    
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled not-allowed" onclick="return false;" href="https://www.example.com" role="button">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of options, but not all of them are equal.

Preferably, wrap your element with a div or span and set the cursor on the wrapper and pointer-events on the content. This way you get all benefits without messing with JS.

Second, you can use the attribute `disabled` on a button, which will make it so that it does not *work*. You can thenset the cursor on the disabled element.

Lastly, but I don't advise it, is using JS to `return false`. Even though this works, I don't like it because: the click event is still triggered (i.e. clicking is still possible but the link is not followed through), meaning you also visually think you clicked the button.

```css
.disabled-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.disabled-wrapper a,
.disabled-wrapper button {
  pointer-events: none;
}

button[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

a.disabled.js-test,
button.disabled.js-test {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="disabled-wrapper"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled not-allowed" href="https://www.example.com" role="button">Test wrapper</a></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled not-allowed" href="https://www.example.com" role="button" disabled>Test disabled attribute</button>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled not-allowed js-test" href="https://www.example.com" role="button" onclick="return false">Test JS</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time not allowed is not work together with the disabled property.
is any one looking for disable with not allowed property here is code.

```
<style>
button
{
  cursor:not-allowed;
}
</style>
<button disabled>
  Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simply**

```html
  <button  class='btn-reserve' type='submit' disabled="true">Submit</button>
```

```
  .btn-reserve:disabled {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
```